# Paste Excel Chart into Powerpoint using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, paste

I'm trying to create an excel macro that copies charts displayed on an excel sheet, and pastes them (paste special) into a PowerPoint. The problem I'm having is how do I paste each chart on a different slide? I do not know the syntax at all..

This is what I have so far (it works but it only pastes to the first sheet):

```
Sub graphics3()

Sheets("Chart1").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
Sheets("Graphs").Select
range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
     With ActiveChart.Parent
     .Height = 425 ' resize
     .Width = 645  ' resize
     .Top = 1    ' reposition
     .Left = 1   ' reposition
 End With

Dim PPT As Object
Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPT.Visible = True
PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:="locationwherepptxis"

Set PPApp = GetObject("Powerpoint.Application")
Set PPPres = PPApp.activepresentation
Set PPSlide = PPPres.slides _
    (PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

' Copy chart as a picture
ActiveChart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, _
    Format:=xlPicture

' Paste chart
PPSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select

' Align pasted chart
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given I dont have your file locations to work with I have attached a routine below that

1. Created a new instance of PowerPoint (late binding, hence the need to define constants for ppViewSlide etc)
2. Loops through each chart in a sheet called Chart1 (as per your example)
3. Adds a new slide
4. Pastes each chart, then repeats

Did you need to format each chart picture before exporting for size, or can you change your default chart size?

```
Const ppLayoutBlank = 2
Const ppViewSlide = 1

Sub ExportChartstoPowerPoint()
    Dim PPApp As Object
    Dim chr
    Set PPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    PPApp.Presentations.Add
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
    For Each chr In Sheets("Chart1").ChartObjects
        PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank
        PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        chr.Select
        ActiveChart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
        PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
        PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
    Next chr
    PPApp.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx Jean-Francois. That is a fair question - the short answer is personal preference. Typically I will late bind if multiple versions of the object being automated are possible, and as I have found users in Q&A forums can struggle with reference setting. Whereas I have used early binging in my Duplicate Master addin as it only binds to the file scripting library, it shaves 20-30% off runtime and as part of the addin it is automatically installed for users.

Answer (score 3):

Code with function for plotting 6 charts from Excel to PPT

```
Option Base 1
Public ppApp As PowerPoint.Application

Sub CopyChart()

Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim oPPTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim myPPT As String
myPPT = "C:\LearnPPT\MyPresentation2.pptx"

Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
'Set oPPTPres = ppApp.Presentations("MyPresentation2.pptx")
Set oPPTPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(Filename:=myPPT)
ppApp.Visible = True
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

i = 1

For Each shp In ws.Shapes

    strShapename = "C" & i
    ws.Shapes(shp.Name).Name = strShapename
    'shpArray.Add (shp)
    i = i + 1

Next shp

Call Plot6Chart(oPPTPres, 2, ws.Shapes(1), ws.Shapes(2), ws.Shapes(3), ws.Shapes(4), ws.Shapes(5), ws.Shapes(6))

End Sub
Function Plot6Chart(pPres As Presentation, SlideNo As Long, ParamArray cCharts())

Dim oSh As Shape
Dim pSlide As Slide
Dim lLeft As Long, lTop As Long

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set pSlide = pPres.Slides(SlideNo)

For i = 0 To UBound(cCharts)

    cCharts(i).Copy
    ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide SlideNo
    pSlide.Shapes.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


    If i = 0 Then ' 1st Chart
        lTop = 0
        lLeft = 0
    ElseIf i = 1 Then ' 2ndChart
        lLeft = lLeft + 240
    ElseIf i = 2 Then ' 3rd Chart
        lLeft = lLeft + 240
    ElseIf i = 3 Then ' 4th Chart
        lTop = lTop + 270
        lLeft = 0
    ElseIf i = 4 Then ' 5th Chart
        lLeft = lLeft + 240
    ElseIf i = 5 Then ' 6th Chart
        lLeft = lLeft + 240
    End If

    pSlide.Shapes(cCharts(i).Name).Left = lLeft
    pSlide.Shapes(cCharts(i).Name).Top = lTop

Next i

Set oSh = Nothing
Set pSlide = Nothing
Set oPPTPres = Nothing
Set ppApp = Nothing
Set pPres = Nothing

End Function
```