# How to copy a chart from Excel to PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Is there any way I could copy a chart from an excel spreadsheet to a powerpoint, **preserving the original formatting and embedding the data**? There was already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492519/paste-excel-chart-into-powerpoint-using-vba)
about copy pasting charts programmatically. However, there was nothing said about data embedding

The biggest problem is embedding the data. As far as I know data embedding requires recreating the chart from the beginning in the power point. (PS: By embedding i do not mean linking to an external excel file.)

Comment: This is not a duplicate!. The question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492519/paste-excel-chart-into-powerpoint-using-vba does not cover data embedding

Comment: Ok now to your problem. What do u mean by `embed data programmatically`

Comment: When user right clicks on the chart in the .ppt slide, then chooses "Edit Data" an Excel spreadsheet "Chart in Microsoft PowerPoint - Microsoft Excel" should pop up containing the corresponding dataset.

Comment: I say programmatically because, I can build the chart within the .ppt slide from the very beginning manually, but this is too much tedious

Comment: It is easier and more efficient to build charts in Excel. And then copy paste them to .ppt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need to do is invoke the PasteSpecial "Keep Source Formatting and Embed Workbook".

[image]

Assume you have already created the charts, and the slides, placeholders/etc., and you have already copied the chart and navigated to the destination slide, and that you have an object like `PPTApp` to represent the `PowerPoint.Application` object.

Instead of using the `Shapes.PasteSpecial` method, you can do this:

```
PPTApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelChartSourceFormatting"
```

This does not create a link to the Excel document, it embeds a local copy of the document in the PowerPoint Presentation.  I think I understand this is your requirement.

**Update from comments**

Documentation on the `ExecuteMso` method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419.aspx

Downloadable document containing the `idMSO` parameters for each Office Application:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6627

**NOTE:** If you want to do something with the pasted chart after `.ExecuteMso` you may need to check if the shape is already pasted because `.ExcecuteMso` is asynchronous (the macro doesn't know when it's finished). Another question shows you how to [wait for its completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711293/powerpoint-vba-does-not-recognize-excel-table-during-run) .

Comment: Thank You so much. It was really hard for me to explain what i want. Finally i got the answer

Comment: No problem. This was a tricky one, I figured it should be an option of the `PasteSpecial` method, but it was not.  `Application.CommandBars` is not very intuitive, so it was more difficult to figure this out.

Comment: Hello David, I have been trying hard to resolve it, whenever i use **ExecuteMso** method, macro is failing with different errors each time, but with **pastespecial** method macro runs successfully, but it wont give the sourcce format, I am pasting total 40 shapes from 20 excel sheets. please help.

Comment: Remark: If you want to do something with the pasted chart after .ExecuteMso you have to check if the shape is already pasted because .ExcecuteMso is **asynchronous** (the macro doesn't know when it's finished). Another questions shows you how to [wait for its completion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711293/powerpoint-vba-does-not-recognize-excel-table-during-run)