# Best Way to Copy Excel Table into PowerPoint (2010)?

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm trying to get a series of Excel tables into PowerPoint and successfully created a macro for this in Office 2013, but am trying to adapt it to Office 2010.

The issue is when pasting the table to PowerPoint, Office 2010 seems to require a unique/different code.

Originally I had:

```
'Copying Tables to PowerPoint
Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide

For i = 0 To Table3
    Sheets("Charts").Range(ChartStart, ChartEnd).Offset(i * Row2, 0).Copy
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(1)
    Set PPShape = PPSlide.Shapes.Paste
    PPShape.Name = "Table" & i
```

But have since been informed a fix for 2010 versions is to use .PasteSpecial so I have:

```
'Copying Tables to PowerPoint
Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide

For i = 0 To Table3
    Sheets("Charts").Range(ChartStart, ChartEnd).Offset(i * Row2, 0).Copy
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(1)
    Set PPShape = PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(dataType:=10)
    PPShape.Name = "Table" & i
```

The thing is using DataType:=10 puts the chart into PowerPoint in an incorrect format for my purposes. I need to get the table into PowerPoint as a table using ppPasteHTML, however, when I try to enter this into the PasteSpecial function I get an error code saying the Clip board is empty.

Does anyone know if "ppPasteHTML' has a numeric equivalent for the DataType option in PasteSpecial? Or another way to get an Excel table into PowerPoint as a table for Office 2010?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble Copying Table from Excel to PowerPoint with VBA in Excel 2010 but not Excel 2013?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556397/trouble-copying-table-from-excel-to-powerpoint-with-vba-in-excel-2010-but-not-ex)

Comment: You **really** shouldn't ask the same question twice in one day...

Comment: I have closed the other one as it didn't have any answers. You msy continue with this one

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

Just make sure you are loading the PowerPoint Library in Excel.

Tools->References->"Microsoft PowerPoint nn.n Object Library"

Also I assume that `Table3`, `ChartStart`, `ChartEnd` & `Row2` have set values

```
Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

'Open PowerPoint and create a new presentation.
Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add

Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)

For i = 0 To Table3
Set objRange = Worksheets("Charts").Range(ChartStart, ChartEnd).Offset(i * Row2, 0)
objRange.Copy
pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteHTML, Link:=msoFalse
Next i

For j = 1 To pptSlide.Shapes.Count
    With pptSlide.Shapes(j)
    .Name = "Table" & j
    End With
Next j

Set pptSlide = Nothing
Set pptPres = Nothing
Set pptApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

The long/numeric equivalent for `ppPasteHtml` is `8`. You can query this for yourself by opening up the VBE in PowerPoint, and doing `?ppPasteHTML` in the Immediate window, or `Debug.Print ppPasteHtml` in a module/routine.

Using early binding, try:

```
pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecialy DataType:=ppPasteHtml
```

Or, using late binding:

```
pptSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=8
```

Alternatively, I have seen a few [other q's where people have problems pasting from one application to another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433826/error-pasting-excel-chart-into-powerpoint-vba/25434525#25434525) (e.g., from Excel to PowerPoint etc.)  In those cases, it seems that sometimes the only way to resolve is to use the `CommandBars` object, however I am not sure if there is an "HTML" paste method from CommandBars.

```
pptSlide.Parent.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableSourceFormatting"
```

Here are some other possible MSO commands you could use, but like I said I don't see one that appears to paste HTML, although this list is for Office 2010:

[image]