# How can I paste a table and keep formatting from Excel to Powerpoint?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste a table from Excel to Powerpoint and keep the source formatting (as a table).

Currently using this to paste:

```
'Paste to PowerPoint and position
 mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteSourceFormatting,    DisplayAsIcon:=msoFalse
 Set myShapeRange = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
```

This was working before, but at that time I wasn't selecting a dynamic range and creating a table from it, the table already existed and this code worked fine.

I've tried many different things today, but my knowledge of VB isn't good enough to figure the issue out. Hopefully someone can be my saviour!

The entire code is below:

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()

'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Range Into a New PowerPoint Presentation

Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim myShapeRange As PowerPoint.Shape

'Refresh UsedRange (get rid of "Ghost" cells)
  Worksheets("Task List1").UsedRange

'Select UsedRange
  Worksheets("Task List1").UsedRange.Select


    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ActiveSheet.UsedRange, , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
    Range("Table1[#All]").Select

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9"
    Range("I10").Select

'Copy Range from Excel
  Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next

    'Is PowerPoint already opened?
      Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
      If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
  PowerPointApp.Visible = True
  PowerPointApp.Activate

'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("Y:\Projects\VBa\2932 2 Milestones.pptx")

'Add a slide to the Presentation
  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Item(1)

'Delete Current table from Powerpoint
  myPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2).Delete

'Wait for a few seconds to catch up
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:3"))

'Copy Excel Range
  rng.Copy
  'ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteSourceFormatting, DisplayAsIcon:=msoFalse
  'PowerPointApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteSourceFormatting")
  Set myShapeRange = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

    'Set position:
      myShapeRange.Left = 20
      myShapeRange.Top = 100
      myShapeRange.Height = 400
      myShapeRange.Width = 675

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: That is not VB.Net code.  Please remove the tag

Comment: have you tried copying it as an image?

Comment: FYR... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558354/best-way-to-copy-excel-table-into-powerpoint-2010

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this because most of you will probably laugh:

> It helps to save the workbook as a macro enabled one first before
>   doing fun stuff with VB.

Yes, I did facepalm.