# Paste Excel range to PowerPoint table with given font and font-color

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I followed this example to paste an Excel range to a PowerPoint table:

```
Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oPPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim SlideNum As Integer

Sub PPTableMacro()

Dim strPresPath As String, strExcelFilePath As String, strNewPresPath As String
strPresPath = "H:\PowerPoint\Presentation1.ppt"
strNewPresPath = "H:\PowerPoint\new1.ppt"

Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
oPPTApp.Visible = msoTrue
Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(strPresPath)
SlideNum = 1
oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select
Set oPPTShape = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes("Table1")

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
oPPTShape.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(1, 1).Text
oPPTShape.Table.Cell(1, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(1, 2).Text
oPPTShape.Table.Cell(1, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(1, 3).Text
oPPTShape.Table.Cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(2, 1).Text
oPPTShape.Table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(2, 2).Text
oPPTShape.Table.Cell(2, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(2, 3).Text

oPPTFile.SaveAs strNewPresPath
oPPTFile.Close
oPPTApp.Quit

Set oPPTShape = Nothing
Set oPPTFile = Nothing
Set oPPTApp = Nothing

MsgBox "Presentation Created", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
End Sub
```

This works fine, but my problem is, I want to paste with the font-color and fon- type used in Excel. Can't find a way to make that work. I tried to use "PasteSpecial" but nothing seems to work as I want to paste directly to a given PowerPoint table.

Someone got an idea?

For example, if i copy by hand colored numbers in an Excel sheet, an paste them directly by hand in a PowerPoint table, it is possible to keep the format. But as I cant record macros in PP, and can't find out how to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905009/how-can-i-paste-a-table-and-keep-formatting-from-excel-to-powerpoint

Comment: This does not help me with pasting to a given presentation with a given PowerPoint table.

Comment: I suspect you'll have to pick up the font characteristics from each cell in Excel and apply it to the text in PPT as you add it.  A single function (to which you pass the PPT cell address and the XL cell address could probably handle it all, including getting the text.