# Shapes (Unknown Member) Pasting from Excel into Powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, powerpoint

I'm having an issue when trying to copy a range from Excel and paste into Powerpoint using VBA.

I receive the following error: `Run-time error (80048240) Shapes (unknown member): Invalid request. Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here.`

The error is thrown in the following code using Excel 2010 and Powerpoint 2010:

```
ws.Range("A1:Y" & lastRow).Copy

pApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 2
pApp.ActiveWindow.Panes(2).Activate

With .Slides(2).Shapes
    .PasteSpecial (ppPasteHTML) `<~~~ Error occurs here!`
End With
```

This only occurs when using the `ppPasteHTML` option or the `ppPasteDefault` option.

The clipboard is definitely not empty and I can manually paste the range as HTML using the paste special menu option in Powerpoint which is confusing me as this is what the error indicates the issue is.

I've researched several question, none of which have helped. They indicated that I needed to activate the slide first prior to pasting which the above code will do but the error is thrown.

Can anyone suggest the reason for the error and how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Slides(2).PasteSpecial("Html") ?

Comment: @Slai The `PasteSpecial` method expects a data type of `PpPasteDataType` see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745158.aspx

Comment: My bad. there doesn't seem to be a separate slide.pastespecial as in Excel. Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558354/best-way-to-copy-excel-table-into-powerpoint-2010.

Comment: Also, the code does not show what ` .Slides` refers to so you can try `With Slides(2).Shapes` without the dot or `With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes`

Comment: Probably related to this, I had a problem like that in excel 2013, while parsing charts from excel, in some PCs it stopped in the debugger and said there was nothing in the clipboard to paste but then press F8 and the command was performed. My solution was to add an application.wait (you may try a sleep as well). Always when working with external applications you'd need to do something to fill the gap the processor may have when executing commands `Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")`

Comment: @Sgdva Thanks for the suggestion, just tried it not no avail unfortunately :-(

Comment: before pasting, make sure your presentation is active. tried it on my end, worked without error.

Comment: @cyboashu I've just tried activating the Powerpoint application to no avail. Could you share a sample of code in an answer to articulate please?

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't manged to solve the issue but as a work around, I'm using the following mso command:

```
ws.Range("A1:Y" & lastRow).Copy

pApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 2
pApp.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate

pApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("Paste") '<~~ Pastes as default HTML table`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (from the PowerPoint side):

```
   Set sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide
   ws.Range("A1:Y" & lastRow).Copy
   sld.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteHTML
```