# Run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)': Shapes (unknown number): Invalid request. Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, clipboard

I have an excel workbook and I want to export the table in sheet1 to PowerPoint using VBA. Below is my code, but I received the error message as the tile. Can anyone help me resolve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Module1()

Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application

ppApp.Visible = True
ppApp.Activate

Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Add
Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutBlank)
ppSlide.Select

Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy

ppSlide.Shapes.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Try slipping a `DoEvents` between the `.Copy` and the `.Paste`.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon Don't quite understand your answer...Can you provide the code? Thx

Comment: @Jancos add the line `DoEvents` after `Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy`.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks. But I still get the error message.     
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
                                                   DoEvents
    ppSlide.Shapes.Paste

Comment: Hmm I think the clipboard is finicky. What about any of the ideas from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433826/error-pasting-excel-chart-into-powerpoint-vba)?

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the link. I got the same error with thatpost. Maybe something wrong with MS Excel 201. lol