# VBA excel charts and tables to PowerPoint specific pages

Tags: excel, vba

I’ve been trying to do this using my very limited coding knowledge. But how do I copy paste particular charts and tables in my excel sheet onto particular pages in my presentation?
Some need to be copied as pictures but most as chart objects. 
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433826/error-pasting-excel-chart-into-powerpoint-vba/25434525#25434525

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185788/how-to-copy-a-chart-from-excel-to-powerpoint/19187572#19187572