# Vba code to copy image from cell into word document

Tags: excel, vba

I am running the code below from a command button in `VBA` in `Excel`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim objWord As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report")
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\Christopher\Desktop\EIG\ReportTemplate.docx" 

With objWord.ActiveDocument
    .Bookmarks("User").Range.Text =ws.Range("A1").Value
    .Bookmarks("Type").Range.Text =ws.Range("A2").Value
End With

Set objWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

It wont copy any images from the worksheet. How would I amend the above to get the images/pictures to copy to a bookmark in the document?

Comment: Does the cell actually contain an *image*? If so, you can't use the cell `.Value`, you need to copy the image (png, jpg, etc.) and paste that to word. If that's the case, then not quite a duplicate, but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19185788/how-to-copy-a-chart-from-excel-to-powerpoint/19187572#19187572) to get you in the right direction. You'll most likely need to use the `Copy` method in Excel and then the `ExecuteMSO` method in Word.

Comment: Yes, there is another commandbutton which i use to paste the image from the clipboard into a specific cell, where it is shown as 'Picture 1'. I am then looking to use the above code to copy everything from the worksheet to the relevant bookmarks in the word document.

Comment: Can you post the code for pasting the image to a specific cell?