# VBA word formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word

What I have so far copies the list of equipment, however the bold formatting is incorrect. Only the first row should be bold, but it bolds everything.

```
'Equipment Algorithm
    Dim equip As Integer
    equip = 11
    Do While Sheet2.Cells(equip, 5).Value <> 0
    Sheet2.Rows(equip).Copy
    wdapp.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
    equip = equip + 1
    Loop
    .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `CommandBars.ExecuteMSO` method, with the `"PasteSourceFormatting"` argument:

```
Dim rng as Range
With Sheet2

    Do While .Cells(equip, 5).Value <> 0
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(equip), .Cells(equip,.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        rng.Copy
        wdapp.CommandBars.ExecuteMSO "PasteSourceFormatting"
        DoEvents
        equip = equip + 1
    Loop

End With
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19187572/1467082) answer for some links to more detail on the `ExecuteMSO` method.

Comment: Not sure what the error is, but it looks like you're trying to copy the *entire row* in to Word, which is probably overkill and I do get a (different) error if I try to copy an entire row. How many columns do you need copied in to word?

Comment: It depends how many are filled, as the algorithm goes. Usually 10-15

Comment: OK, so can you modify your code to copy the specific range that you need, rather than the entire row?

Comment: No, because we want everything in the row, and we don't want to have to change the code every time the circumstances change

Comment: Ok, let's take a step back: It **is** possible to construct your code in such a manner that it can dynamically derive the "length" of the row.  Now, can you do that?

Comment: NB: my revised answer shows a possible solution to that predicament.

Comment: Well, you can try my suggestion. And you can look at other related questions on SO or other forums like "How to find the last used cell in a row" etc. and I bet you will be able to figure it out :)

Comment: You're not helping yourself. I shouldn't have to keep asking you what you mean by "this doesn't work". I have tested this code, and it does work when I test it. Perhaps you should spend some additional time debugging/troubleshooting from your end to see what might be the specific problem. Consider reviewing [ask] and also providing a [mcve] that demonstrates the error condition(s).

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the with .selection thats called out before this code, however, when I end and start it it after the code it still gives me Error number 5 `'Equipment Algorithm
End With
 Dim equip As Integer
    equip = 11
Dim rng As range

With Sheet2

    Do While .Cells(equip, 5).Value <> 0
    Set rng = .range(.Cells(equip), .Cells(equip, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        rng.Copy
        wdapp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"
        DoEvents
        equip = equip + 1
    Loop

End With
 With .Selection`

Comment: It's impossible to read multiline code statements in the comments, please consider revising your question to include additional code :)