# How to create a powerpoint table using powershell

Tags: powershell, powerpoint

I'm currently trying to create a calendar in powerpoint using powershell. All I want to do is **insert a table into a powerpoint slide.** This table is representing the month of January, it contains the days of the week etc.

I did some research and came across [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/10/16/how-can-i-copy-data-from-excel-to-powerpoint.aspx?Redirected=true).

This is VB script, so i tried to "create its equivalent" in powershell:

**EDIT3:** I was finally able to copy my table from Excel and paste it into my powerpoint slide using this code:

```
#Create an instance of Excel.
$xl=New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$xl.Visible = $True

#Open the Excel file containing the table. 
$wb = $xl.workbooks.open("C:\January.xls")
$ws = $wb.ActiveSheet

#Select the table.
$range = $ws.range("A1:G7")
$range.select()

#Copy the table to the clipboard.
$range.copyPicture()

#Create an instance of Powerpoint.
$objPPT = New-Object -ComObject "Powerpoint.Application"
$objPPT.Visible ='Msotrue'

#Add a slide to the presentation.    
$project = $objPPT.Presentations.Add()
$slide  = $project.Slides.Add(1, 1)

#Paste the table into the slide.
$shape = $slide.Shapes.Paste()

#Position the table.
$shape.Left = 50
$shape.Top = 150
$shape.Width = 300
$shape.Height = 168
```

Thanks to those who have helped me here and on #powershell

Comment: Show the code that you created in trying to convert the VBS to PowerShell.

Comment: @arloc 
I didn't do much since i'm kind of new to powershell, but here's what i tried: http://pastebin.com/8sqQptFb

Comment: And in what way did you "not succeed"? Describe what your end goal is, what you did, what you got, and where exactly you're stuck/things aren't working as expected. There's at least one bug I see in how you're handling app visibility (hint: compare `$objPPT.Visible` and `$xl.Visible`)

Comment: @alroc Thank you for replying to me. I made a few changes to the code I was trying to "convert": http://pastebin.com/khvL0Lm7
If I use this script to paste my table into a word document, this is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/GsnHvwE.jpg 
a nice table that I can move and resize, this is exactly what I need to do. However, If I use the script to paste the table into a powerpoint slide I get an error (refer to the original poste, above). Also, I did compare `$objPPT.Visible` and `$xl.Visible` but i chose to use `'Msotrue'` on purpose. I get an error if I don't do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw your question in the channel.
This worked for me:

```
$presentation = $ppt.Presentations.Open($ifile)
$sl = $presentation.Slides.Add(1, $ppLayoutBlank) 
$shape = $sl.shapes.paste()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, it worked but I had to use `$range.copyPicture()` instead of `$range.copy()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:

```
# Optionally, make sure you're on the last slide:
$ppt.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide( $ppt.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count )

# Specify the 
$ppt.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial( "ppPasteOLEObject", "msoFalse",  "", 0, "", "msoFalse")
```

See the 
  [MSDN Interop Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.view.pastespecial%28v=office.14%29.aspx) 
and thanks to this example:
  [Paste Excel Chart into Powerpoint using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492519/paste-excel-chart-into-powerpoint-using-vba)