# Copying and pasting charts in PowerPoint with VBA while preserving location and size

Tags: excel, vba, module, powerpoint

My question is quite simple but I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Here it is:
I do want to copy a chart from a slide and paste it to another with VBA.

I am doing it manually and it is time consuming for no reason, there are a lot of charts like that. I do want to automize it.

To be more specific:

- There is a chart in slide number 37 -> [Chart I want to Copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iMiI.png)
- I want to copy that chart in slide number 37 -> [Slide I want to Paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CF7O1.png)
- And paste it to slide 36 while preserving formatting, size, position etc. -> [Wanted final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i84m2.png)

I hope it has an easy solution and I can find anyone who wants to help.
Thanks in advance!

edit:
I can copy charts **excel to powerpoint** using scripts like that:
[Paste Excel Chart into Powerpoint using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492519/paste-excel-chart-into-powerpoint-using-vba)

but cannot find a way for **powerpoint to powerpoint (itself)**

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually I can copy charts excel to powerpoint using scripts like that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492519/paste-excel-chart-into-powerpoint-using-vba

but cannot find a way for powerpoint to powerpoint

Comment: @YahyaDemirbas Please respond to the question braX has asked. What have you tried to do to copy powerpoint to powerpoint?